# SQL Join and compare

Tags: sql, join, compare

I have the following two tables and i would like to compare them on their respective group sizes:

```
create table vehicle1
(
V_id int,
make nvarchar(20),
model nvarchar(20),
group_size1 nvarchar(20),
tech varchar(20)
);

Insert into vehicle1 values
( 1, 'audi', 'q5' ,'34','SLI'),
( 1, 'audi', 'q5' ,'35','SLI'),
( 2, 'mini', 'cooper' ,'35','SLI'),
( 3, 'mazda', 'a3' ,'21','AGM'),
( 4, 'audi', 'q5' ,'H4','SLI');

create table vehicle2
(
V_id int,
make nvarchar(20),
model nvarchar(20),
group_size2 nvarchar(20),
tech varchar(20)
);

Insert into vehicle2 values
( 1, 'audi', 'q5' ,'34','SLI'),
( 1, 'audi', 'q5' ,'35','SLI'),
( 2, 'mini', 'cooper' ,'35','SLI'),
( 3, 'mazda', 'a3' ,'30','AGM'),
( 3, 'mazda', 'a3' ,'21','AGM'),
( 4, 'audi', 'q5' ,'H5','SLI');

expected output:
V_id    make    model   group_size1 group_size2 tech
( 3, 'mazda', 'a3' ,'30', '21','AGM'),
( 4, 'audi', 'q5' , 'H4', 'H5','SLI');

What i tried so far:
SELECT v1.V_id, v1.make, v1.model, v1.group_size1, v2.group_size2, v1.tech
FROM vehicle1 v1
JOIN vehicle2 v2 ON v1.V_id = v2.V_id and v1.make = v2.make and v1.model = v2.model and v1.group_size1 <> v2.group_size2;

Output i got :
( 1, 'audi', 'q5' ,'34', '35','SLI'),
( 1, 'audi', 'q5' ,'35', '34', 'SLI'),
( 3, 'mazda', 'a3' ,'30', '21','AGM'),
( 4, 'audi', 'q5' , 'H4', 'H5','SLI');
```

I dont understand why it is still comparing the group sizes for V_id = 1 and group_size1 = 35 what should i consider to get the desired output?

Comment: your wanted result doesn't make that much sense, and you have multiple identical v_id which complicates the matter  for example 30 for mazda isn't in vehicle1

Comment: The issue is on join with group_size.  Maybe a ```and v1.group_size1 not in  (v2.group_size2) ``` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
WITH v2 AS (
SELECT * FROM vehicle2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM vehicle1
)
SELECT v1.V_id, v1.make, v1.model, v1.group_size1, v2.group_size2, v1.tech 
FROM vehicle1 v1 JOIN v2 ON v1.V_id = v2.V_id and v1.make = v2.make and v1.model = v2.model and v1.group_size1 <> v2.group_size2;
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/1rBvxn5K)

Comment: it will have the same problem, as you have v_id in vehicle 1 twice in it so it will get also multiple results in a join

Comment: Have you tried it: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/1rBvxn5K)

Comment: no the data makes no sense, as long it is not cleared up, all attempts will fail, see my comment, your result in the fiddle is not that what he wants see 30 in vehicle1

Comment: Then his questions don't make sense. The group_size 30 isn't in vehicle1. To understand his problem it is the question why he want the desired output.

Comment: yes that is why is should be closed, till is is clarified

Comment: apologies the data is not exactly how i put it  here, i just assumed a sample of the huge amount of data that we have - for instance these are from two different databases and the business requires us to compare and there is no particular primary key and a combination of multiple columns is what they were going with , so i had to make an example where even the ID repeats